# What do these double Class Bravo airspace floor and ceiling limits mean?

Tags: airspace, aeronautical-charts, flight-level

While browsing [SkyVector](https://skyvector.com/?ll=36.81236324400328,-4.208404530018495&chart=301&zoom=2) I came across these double Class B airspace limits within the same *section* (is that what you call it?). I'm wondering what it means and what the difference is between this and FL145/SFC.

[image]

Comment: https://skyvector.com/?ll=36.81236324400328,-4.208404530018495&chart=301&zoom=2

Comment: Simply a coincidence that you're familiar with the Malaga area @abelenky?

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE!

Comment: Thank you @Pondlife !

Comment: @Basaa:  I read the snippet of Morse Code on the VOR ID (`--   --.  .-`).  **MGA** is the ID for 5 different points worldwide.  It was easy to find the right one.

Comment: @abelenky 200IQ confirmed haha

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The way SkyVector shows airspace is subtly different than shown on FAA charts. Whereas the FAA shows the combined limits in each area, SkyVector shows the limits once for each layer, even where layers overlap.

So, what you are probably seeing here is one area of FL145/35 on top of another area of 35/SFC, possibly disjoint but the labels for both areas just happened to end up near each other. Or, it may be two areas with the same boundaries but different owners or airspace classes. As a result, it’s often difficult to figure out exactly which area(s) each label applies to.

Note that while SkyVector uses official maps from the FAA in/near the US, the rest of the world is computer-generated and not nearly as useful, especially since other countries often use airspace classes in vastly different ways that can’t be represented well in SkyVector’s pseudo-FAA style. Notably, they use blue for all classes, which often confuses folks used to the FAA’s color scheme.

According to the Spanish AIP, they are indeed two stacked airspaces; TMA SEVILLA AREA 3B and TMA SEVILLA AREA 3C. For example, in 3B (the higher one):

> VFR traffic is not allowed, except for State aircraft, helicopters, medical and rescue flights.

Official e-chart here: https://insignia.enaire.es/

Comment: Super useful stuff. Thank you so much for the help guys! Enjoy your weekends!

Comment: They do not use just blue, they also use gray for TRAs and TSAs. Also, our AIP also draws everything in blue https://aim.rlp.cz/vfrmanual/actual/lkpr_text_en.html  I do not think it is inherently bad.

Comment: @VladimirF Can you give examples? I’ve never seen anything but blue on SkyVector. Using blue everywhere is not bad per se, but it does confuse US pilots who are used to blue only being used for class B.

Comment: @StephenS Yes all controlled airspaces are all blue. But gray is used for dangerous spaces, restricted spaces and similar. I have not seen colour coding for different airspace classes in any European AIP. Nor have I seen much class B either...

Comment: @VladimirF SkyVector uses blue and magenta ticked lines for SUA, same as FAA. I don’t see gray lines anywhere.

Comment: If you call it magenta, so be it. There is no magenta colour in my language (we are the side that lost there...) so I am not used to naming this colour this way.